# Derangements question

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

> Let $D_n$ be the number of derangements of $n$ objects and $P_{n,k}$ be the number of permutations of $n$ objects with exactly $k$ ﬁxed points. Give a formula for $P_{n,k}$ in terms of $D_{n−k}$.

In case someone wants the definition of derangements:

> Permutations with no fixed points are called *derangements*. A *fixed point* is a cycle of length $1$.

I am very stuck on this, but this is what I think it is. The total number of permutations on $n$ objects is $n!$, and since there are $k$ fixed points, there must be $n-k$ non-fixed points. So the number of derangements on $n-k$ points is $D_{n-k}$. So $P_{n,k} = n!- D_{n-k}$? I feel like this is wrong and I am undercounting.

I have a feeling the answer is $P_{n,k} = n!- {n \choose k }D_{n-k}$ but I don't know why.

Comment: Hint: How many ways are there to **Choose** the fixed points? The rest must be deranged.

Comment: the no. of ways to choose k fixed points out of n objects is nCk

Comment: That's right. And for **each** such choice there are $D_{n-k}$ derangements of the rest.

Comment: So the answer is n! - (nCk)*D_{n-k}?

Comment: Not quite. It is, in your notation, ${}_nC_kD_{n-k}$, in mine $\binom{n}{k}D_{n-k}$. The number $n!-\binom{n}{k}D_{n-k}$ counts the number of permutations that **do not** have exactly $k$ fixed points, i,e, more than $k$ or fewer than $k$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been provided in the comments. There are $\binom nkD_{n-k}$ permutations with exactly $k$ fixed points, since we can choose $k$ out of $n$ elements in $\binom nk$ ways and derange the remaining elements in $D_{n-k}$ ways.